# How to determine at origin which custom hostname is being requested?

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

If I am using [CloudFlare for SaaS](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-for-platforms/cloudflare-for-saas/#standard-cloudflare-for-saas-configuration) where I have an arbitrary number of clients using custom hostnames, how do I determine on the client what is being requested?

For instance, if the fallback URL is a wild carded "`customers.example.com`"and there are 2 customers, where one is using a custom hostname, how do I determine what is being requested?

- URL requested for customer 1 (no custom hostname): `customer1.customers.example.com`
- URL requested for customer 2 (with custom hostname): `foo.bar.com`

What is passed on to the origin in terms of headers? Both of these requests go to `customers.example.com`, so how do I determine which customer the request is on behalf of? Am I supposed to use CloudFlare Workers? Do I just look at the Host header (does CloudFlare protect against this being injected?)?

Comment: The requests will still come in with the usual `Host` headers as with any other server setup. The CNAME doesn't impact that.

Comment: But does CloudFlare protect against host header injection?

Comment: No more or less than any setup. What specific concern do you have? If someone sends a request to `customers.example.com` with a Host header of `foo.bar.com`, they will get your handling for `foo.bar.com`, yes. If they shouldn't, you need authentication (user logins) of some kind.

Comment: Thanks, that’s helpful, I’m just trying to get clear in my head what the different ways are that traffic arrives at the site and what it looks like when it get there.